# Decimal to IEEE 754 Single-precision IEEE 754 code using C

Tags: c, binary, ieee-754, converters, single-precision

We have an assignment in class to convert from Decimal to single precision using c and I'm completely lost.

This is the assignment:

> The last part of this lab involves coding a short c algorithm. Every
> student must create a program that gets a scientific notation floating
> point number as an input and prints it´s IEE754 single precission
> value both in binary and hexadecimal.
>
> The ouput of the program must be equal to the following :  “Introduce
> a float point number in decimal (scientific notation):  The decimal
> float 1.234500e-04 is 3901725B in hexadecimal (IEEE 754). “

The #includes we have learnt so far are: stdio.h, math.h and string.h, so I don't think we are allowed to use any other includes. Also we havnt learned `struct` or `union` or any of that yet, because I saw those in other examples and I didn't understand anything.

I would really appreciate it if someone can guide me through making this code!

Comment: *"I would really appreciate it if someone can guide me through making this code!"* That is not how this site works. You need to ask specific question, which is answerable with specific answer. Break your problem to smaller problems, then try to solve one smaller problem. If you have issue with that small problem, then ask about that. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

> guide me through making this code!

As OP only requested a guide:

1. **gets a scientific notation floating point number**

Research `scanf()` and the `"%f"` specifier

2. **prints it´s IEE754 single precision value in ... hexadecimal**

Research *type punning* a `float` into `uint32_t`.  Review [Could copy unsigned int bit values as float but float value not returned to the caller function correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45799161/2410359) and avoid pointer tricks.  See [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/2410359)

Research `printf()` and the `"%x"` specifier.

3. **prints ... in ... binary**

There a *many* ways to [Is there a printf converter to print in binary format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111928/2410359).
[Some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641674/2410359) are very general (base, 2,3,10,16,36...)

Comment: I will take a look at the links and try them out, ill let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

The assignment you describe has three parts:

1. Examine the characters of the numeral and convert them into a floating-point number.
2. Print the value of the floating-point number.
3. Print the bytes of a floating-point number.

For 1, it is not clear whether you are intended to write code to do that yourself or to use a library routine. For library routines, use `scanf` (to read from input) or `sscanf` (to read from an array of `char`). If you are to do it yourself, then, at the level you describe, I do not expect an exact solution is required. In this case, you can: Identify the power of ten corresponding to each digit, multiply the digit by the power of ten, and sum the products. For example, with “1.234500e-04”, you would find the exponent, “-04”, convert it to an `int`, then multiply 1 by `pow(10, -5)`, multiply 2 by `pow(10, -6)`, and so on, and then add the products.

For 2, print using `printf`.

For 3, use `memcpy` to copy the bytes from the `float` into a `uint32_t` (look up the header `<stdint.h>`) and print its bytes with `printf` (look up the header `<inttypes.h>` for the correct format specifier to use). Alternatively, use `memcpy` to copy the bytes from the `float` into an array of `char`, then print the `char` using `printf` with a format specifier that prints hexadecimal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will try out the code and let you know how it turns out